# key combination to select current line in vs 2008?

Tags: c#, key, combinations

I just started learning c# on vs 2008.

I found key combiations for

1. select current word
2. delete current line

is there a key combination to select current line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also press CTRL+C to copy the whole line the cursor is currently in. You will not see a selection bar, but the entire line is copied to the clibboard. Then you can press CTRL+V to paste it anywhere you like.

EDIT: Make sure you don't have anything selected in the line, in that case only the selection will be copied to clipboard.

Comment: The question wasn't about copying to the clipboard, but about selecting the current line, e.g. to be used with a macro which operates on selected text.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>HOME</kbd> , <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>END</kbd>

Comment: Or home, home, shift+end if you want to select the indentation too.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ctrl + w.

For more information you visit this user link:
http://smallworkarounds.blogspot.com/2008/12/visual-studio-2008-tips-tricks-for.html

Comment: CTRL + W selects only the word the cursor is currently on, not the line

Comment: ...which basically simulates a double-click